# deleting a an entire directory tree from p4 workspace

Tags: perforce

The following is my folder structure

```
A
 a1
   a11
   a12
   a13
a2
```

i want to delete the entire tree of a1, including the files and subfolders in it.
how to do that using p4 delete. Is it possible to delete folders/ should i empty each and every file from the subfolders.

I have 3000 files in a1. New to perforce hence not sure of the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to specify the path to a1 in you depot and follow with ... at the end.
Example:

```
p4 delete //depot/main/A/a1/...
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that "delete from the workspace" and "delete from the depot" are two different things!

Perforce lets you arbitrarily sync individual files and directories to different revisions, so you have a lot of flexibility over what's in your workspace at any given time -- you can have some files synced to the latest revision and others synced to earlier revisions, and Perforce will track the state of each file individually so that everything can be reconciled later if needed.  To completely remove files from the workspace, just `sync` them to `#none`:

```
p4 sync A/a1/...#none
```

You can easily get these files back later with another `sync` operation.  What you're synced to in your own workspace does not affect anyone else.

---

To open the files for delete (which lets you delete them for EVERYONE, not just you), use `p4 delete`:

```
p4 delete A/a1/...
```

Now the files are "open for delete".  To complete the action of deleting them from the depot, do:

```
p4 submit
```

and now the files are deleted at the head revision -- the next time anyone else syncs these files, they'll be removed from that workspace.

Comment: if i delete all files in a folder, will that folder be deleted too? after p4 submit from my depot ?

Comment: Perforce doesn't track folders independently of files, so once a folder is empty it's effectively deleted.  Note that if you don't set the `rmdir` option in your client spec, empty folders won't be automatically cleaned up from the workspace.